# PhpStorm - как отменить массовое изменение?

Tags: phpstorm, ide

PhpStorm - как отменить массовое изменение (ctrl+shift+h)?
В `Local History` этих изменений не видно.
В Netbeans есть групповая история,  там пишутся такие изменения.
А в PhpStorm есть что-то подобное?

Comment: Тоже не фурычит отмена массовой автозамены, например. Могу посоветовать использовать контроль версий

Answer (score 1):

Может вы каким то образом Local History отменили или работали с файлами которые не являются файлами проекта. Обычно Local History хорошо всё контролирует и решает данную проблему

Comment: Local History показывает только изменения того файла, вкладка которого активна. И откатить может изменения только этого файла. А если изменено несколько файлов? Откатить сразу все как? Каждый из них открывать и откатывать? Должны быть другие средства.

Comment: Можно вызывать Local History для директории, тогда можно увидеть изменения всех ее файлов.

Answer (score 0):

В PHPStorm нажмите комбинацию клавиш <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (Либо в меню нажмите <kbd>View</kbd> затем <kbd>Tool windows</kbd>, и там найдите <kbd>Version Control</kbd>), откроется окно **Local Changes**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там просто выбираем файлы, которые хотим отменить и нажимаем правой клавишей мыши и выбираем <kbd>Revert...</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полезные ссылки:

- [Undo changes. Revert uncommitted changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/undo-changes.html)
- [Reverting Local Changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reverting-local-changes.html)
- [Revert Changes Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/revert-changes-dialog.html)
- [Undoing and Redoing Changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/undoing-and-redoing-changes.html)

Comment: А как выбрать файлы? Нужно лазить в дереве проекта и открывать каждый файл, который я хочу "откатить"? И у него смотреть Local History? Ведь Local History показывает только тот файл, вкладка которого активна. Или там можно как-то переключаться между файлами?
Прикладываю скриншот. Открыта вкладка файла style.css. Local History и показывает изменения в нем. Если нажму Revert, откатится только он (даже если нажал Revert у пункта с 3 файлами).
https://ibb.co/cMZSNG

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno я у себя в окне  *Local Changes* просто выбираю файлы, которые хочу откатить и нажимаю кнопку **Revert** - все исправно работает (отмена массового изменения). Не знаю, что у вас за беда...у меня официальная лицензия на PHPStorm. И не понимаю, зачем лазить в дереве и искать, вы просили массовую отмену - вот она, жмите хоть **Ctr+A** и отменяйте - все работает.

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno я вообще-то не про *Local History* говорю, а про *Local Changes* - это немного не то. *Local History* находится на вкладке **VCS->Local History->Show History**

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno посмотрите внимательно в мой ответ, я там подробно описал как туда попасть.  **Local History** и **Local Changes** - разные пункты.

Comment: Это нужно смотреть, какие файлы менялись во время Replace in Path. И перед самой операцией Replace in Path нужно эти файлы как-то сохранить (чтобы было к чему Revert'ить), да?

Comment: @AlexandrNevajno ну как бы для того, чтобы отменить, нужно знать, что отменять. К примеру можно посмотреть на список измененных файлов в *Local History*, как-то запомнить и потом через *Local Changes* отменить эти изменения. Нужно минимизировать количество логических действий в одном ченьджсете, чтобы не возникало потом путаницы.

Comment: В Netbeans все куда проще.

Answer (score 0):

Я научился отменять изменения во всех файлах в PhpStorm. Просто нужно нажать Ctrl+Z. Там выскочит диалоговое окно - "Undo Replace"? Жмем OK. И отменяются изменения во ВСЕХ файлах. Если делать через VCS->Local History->Show History, то только в одном файле. Жаль, что нельзя через историю - если после массового изменения были еще какие-то изменения, то их тоже придется отменить - чтобы дойти до массового изменения.